# How to use `assigns` with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

Hiho,

I have the following test:

```
  test "should annoy Chuck Norris" do
    son = Factory.build(:son)
    assert_difference('Son.count') do
      post :create, son: { asset: son.asset, chuck_id: son.chuck }
    end

    assert_redirected_to chuck_path(assigns(son.chuck))
    assert_equal 'The world has been destroyed...', flash[:notice]
  end
```

`assigns(son.chuck)` doens't work, when I try `son.chuck`, it works, but after running all my tests and creating some `Chucks`, `Factory.build(:son)` created a `Chuck` with id `12` and the `assert_redirected_to` are sending id `1`. Resulting the following error:

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/chucks/12> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/chucks/1>
          /Users/edison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/response.rb:67:in `assert_redirected_to'
```

So how can I get the correct `Chuck.id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking to use is `assigns(:chuck).son`.

The argument to assigns must match the variable name in the controller. In other words, assuming you have `@chuck.son` in the controller, you should use `assigns(:chuck).son`. Note how the argument corresponds to what come right after the `@` symbol.

Comment: Yeeep, you are the master! ;]

Comment: `assigns` has nothing related with Factory Girl. Im dumb!